# Format and TeXForm does not work as expected

Tags: bugs, output-formatting, latex

Recently, we had a [nice question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47364/187) which brought up an issue that I believe is a bug. In the tutorial [Defining Output Formats](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/DefiningOutputFormats.html), there is an example at the end which doesn't make sense:

> This specifies the `TeXForm` for the symbol `x`.
>
> ```
> Format[x, TeXForm] := "{\\bf x}"
> ```
>
> The output format for `x` that you specified is now used whenever the TeX form is needed.
>
> ```
> TeXForm[1 + x^2] 
> (* x^2+1 *)
> ```

The given output is wrong and should instead be something like `{\bf x}^2+1`. Therefore, I tested this with [my colleague](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9453/udb) on all versions available to us and the output below shows, that it only worked back in version 4.2.

Is there a simple reason why `Format` does not work as advertised?

#### Version 4.2

```
Format[x,TeXForm]:="{\\bf x}";
TeXForm[1+x^2]
(* 1 + {{\bf x}}^2 *)
```

#### Version 5.1

```
Format[x,TeXForm]:="{\\bf x}";
TeXForm[1+x^2]
(* x^2+1 *)
```

#### Version 6.0

```
Format[x, TeXForm] := "{\\bf x}";
TeXForm[1 + x^2]
(* x^2+1 *)
```

#### Version 7.0

```
Format[x, TeXForm] := "{\\bf x}";
TeXForm[1 + x^2]
(* x^2+1 *)
```

#### Version 8.0

```
Format[x, TeXForm] := "{\\bf x}";
TeXForm[1 + x^2]
(* x^2+1 *)
```

#### Version 9.0

```
Format[x, TeXForm] := "{\\bf x}";
TeXForm[1 + x^2]
(* x^2+1 *)
```

Comment: From Mathematica's help: `Format[s]:=rhs defines a symbol s to print like rhs.`

Comment: @GregoryRut How does that answer the question?

Comment: Has `Format` ever worked (reliably) as advertised? Not in my experience. Just use `MakeBoxes` instead; forget about `Format`. :)

Comment: @OleksandrR.MakeBoxes does not work with TeXForm as its second argument.

Comment: @RolfMertig it works with any `$BoxForms`, which are `StandardForm` and `TraditionalForm`. These are called by `TeXForm` on its argument, and the latter then *displays as* the $\TeX$ corresponding to the resulting boxes. It isn't the most elegant approach, I admit, but without knowledge of how the `TeXForm` display is obtained internally (probably the the FE sees it and produces some special boxes?), this hijacking seems to be the best we can do.

Comment: I would report this to support@wolfram.com

Comment: @chuy I have already reported it as bug.

Comment: It seems to work if you replace `TeXForm` with `InputForm`, suggesting that the problem is mainly associated with `TeXForm` rather than `Format`. Please keep us updated on the response to the bug report.

Comment: Also, the example `Format[bin[x_, y_], TeXForm] := MatrixForm[{{x}, {y}}]` in the `TeXForm` reference *does* work...

Comment: Note: the `Format` rule is applied in `TeXForm[x]`.  It is possible that a format is applied in `TeXForm` only when it matches the whole expression.

Comment: I have added the 'bugs' tag because TeXForm does not work as advertised in the documentation. Either it or the documentation need to change.

Answer (score 14):

### What `Format` does

Role of `Format`, as I understand it, is to set appropriate transformation rules. One can check those rules using `FormatValues` function:

```
Format[x, TeXForm] = "{\\bf x}";
FormatValues[x] // FullForm
(* List[RuleDelayed[HoldPattern[Format[x, TeXForm]], "{\\bf x}"]] *)
```

One can also see those rules by inspecting symbol for which rules where set:

```
?x
(* Global`x *)
(* x/:Format[x,TeXForm]={\bf x} *)
```

So `Format` alone correctly assigns proper transformation rules. It's `TeXForm` that is not using them as it should.

---

### What `TeXForm` does

There are two problems with how `TeXForm` works.

**Problem 1**: When formatting rules are used, what we have set as RHS of `Format` is not used verbatim, but converted to $\TeX$.

As it's noted in [comment by @MichaelE2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47417/format-and-texform-does-not-work-as-expected/#comment-141017),
if we pass expression with defined rules directly to `TeXForm`

```
TeXForm[x]
(* \text{$\{\backslash \backslash $bf x$\}$} *)
```

transformation rules are used, but string `"{\\bf x}"` is converted to $\TeX$.

**Problem 2**: Formatting rules are not used for subexpressions of expression passed to `TeXForm`.

```
TeXForm[1 + x^2]
(* x^2+1 *)
```

How `TeXForm` works under the hood is described in [answers to question mentioned by OP](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47364/texform-and-large-brackets-biggl-etc).

As stated in Properties & Relations section of [`Format` documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Format.html?q=Format&lang=en) `MakeBoxes` use formatting rules added by `Format`. `MakeBoxes` is used by `TeXForm`, but as noted in [comment by @RolfMertig](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47417/format-and-texform-does-not-work-as-expected/#comment-140717) and explained in [comment by @OleksandrR.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47417/format-and-texform-does-not-work-as-expected/#comment-140718) `TeXForm` is not one of `$BoxForms` and internally `TeXForm` converts expression to boxes in `TraditionalForm`. So formatting rules for `TeXForm` are just not used anywhere.

---

### How to work around `TeXForm` problems

**Problem 1**

To deal with it we can define a wrapper that, when converted to $\TeX$, will return its content verbatim:

```
TeXVerbatim::usage = "TeXVerbatim[\"str\"] converted to TeX gives verbatim \"str\"."
```

Let's use `` System`Convert`TeXFormDump`maketex `` to force appropriate $\TeX$ conversion:

```
System`Convert`TeXFormDump`maketex[
    RowBox[{
        "TeXVerbatim",
        "(" | "[", 
        arg_String?(StringMatchQ[#, "\"" ~~ ___ ~~ "\""] &), 
        ")" | "]"
    }]
] :=
    ToExpression[arg]
```

This is the only place where we'll use this internal function and only "box pattern" we need to write by hand.
Let's check that it works:

```
TeXVerbatim["\\macro $1+1$ \\command[a=b]{c}"] // TeXForm
(* \macro $1+1$ \command[a=b]{c} *)
```

Now use it in `Format`:

```
Format[x, TeXForm] := TeXVerbatim["{\\bf x}"]
TeXForm[x]
(* {\bf x} *)
```

**Problem 2**

First let's define function that applies relevant rules to given expression:

```
ApplyTeXFormFormat::usage =
    "ApplyTeXFormFormat[expr] returns expr with all subexpressions that \
    have custom TeX formating rules replaced with their TeX form."

ApplyTeXFormFormat[expr_] :=
    expr /.
        Flatten[
            Cases[
                (* Get formating rules, *)
                FormatValues[#]
                ,
                (* take only rules defined for TeXFormat *)
                HoldPattern[HoldPattern[HoldPattern][Format[x_, TeXForm]] :> xTeX_] :>
                    (* and change them to replacement rules for bare transformed expression. *)
                    (HoldPattern[x] :> xTeX)
            ] & /@
                (* Perform above for all symbols found in expr. *)
                DeleteDuplicates[
                    Cases[expr, _Symbol, {0, Infinity}, Heads -> True]]
                ]
        ]
```

Since those rules transform expression and not low level boxes they could be used anywhere before `MakeBoxes` is called on expression passed to `TeXForm`.

We can either define own function that will apply transformation rules and convert expression to $\TeX$:

```
TeXFormAll::usage =
    "TeXFormAll[expr] prints TeX version of expr with custom formating \
    applied to each subexpression."

TeXFormAll[expr_] := TeXForm[ApplyTeXFormFormat[expr]]

TeXFormAll[1 + x^2]
(* {\bf x}^2+1 *)
```

or redefine built in `` Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX `` function so that `TeXForm` will work as expected:

```
Unprotect[Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX];

Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX[expr_, opts___?OptionQ] :=
    Convert`TeX`BoxesToTeX[
        ToBoxes[ApplyTeXFormFormat[expr], TraditionalForm],
        opts,
        "BoxRules" -> System`Convert`TeXFormDump`$GreekWords
     ]

Protect[Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX];

TeXForm[1 + x^2]
(* {\bf x}^2+1 *)
```

---

### Package

I've created a package implementing above concepts together with some additional functions to customize TeX output. 
It is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/jkuczm/MathematicaTeXUtilities).

Its example usage could be:

```
Get["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jkuczm/MathematicaTeXUtilities/master/TeXUtilities/TeXUtilities.m"]
Get["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jkuczm/MathematicaTeXUtilities/master/TeXUtilities/FormatTeXFormPatch.m"]


Format[something, TeXForm] = TeXVerbatim["\\macro $1+1$ \\command[a=b]{c}"];

Format[f[x__], TeXForm] := TeXDelimited["\\left(", x, "\\right)", "DelimSeparator" -> ""]

Format[g[x__], TeXForm] := TeXCommand["g", {{a -> b}, x}]

Format[h[x__], TeXForm] := TeXEnvironment["myEnv", x]

h[
    f[1 + alpha],
    5 - g[3, g[2]],
    something
] // TeXForm
(*
\begin{myEnv}
\left(\alpha +1\right)
5-\g[a=b]{3}{\g[a=b]{2}}
\macro $1+1$ \command[a=b]{c}
\end{myEnv}
*)
```

Comment: Thank you for the detective work!

Answer (score 10):

If someone is after an easy workaround, then here it is: First, you have to initialise the TeX conversion system by simply calling something like `TeXForm[1]` when you are working on a fresh Kernel.

After that it is simply

```
System`Convert`TeXFormDump`maketex["x"] = "{\\bf x}";
TeXForm[x^2 + 1]
(* {\bf x}^2+1 *)
```

For a detailed explanation, please see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/47560/187).

**Note that this only works around the issue and doesn't explain, why it is not working as described.**

Answer (score 6):

**This is not an answer, but a comment to [halirutans answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47417/format-and-texform-does-not-work-as-expected#answer-47561) that is to big for a comment.**

It's important to stress that, if we want special `TeXForm` for an expression, argument given to `` System`Convert`TeXFormDump`maketex `` should be low level box representation of that expression in `TraditionalForm`.

For symbol it's just string with symbols name:

```
TeXForm[1](* initialise *)

System`Convert`TeXFormDump`maketex["x"] = "\\text{special TeXForm of x}";
TeXForm[1 + x]
(* \text{special TeXForm of x}+1 *)
```

For complicated expressions we can use `MakeBoxes`:

```
System`Convert`TeXFormDump`maketex[MakeBoxes[f[a, b], TraditionalForm]] = "\\f[a]{b}";
TeXForm[1 + f[a, b]]
(* \f[a]{b}+1 *)
```

But if one wants special `TeXForm` of any expression matching given pattern, it's more complicated.

```
System`Convert`TeXFormDump`maketex[MakeBoxes[g[a_], TraditionalForm]] := "\\g{" <> a <> "}"
TeXForm[g[a + 1]]
(* g(a+1) *)
```

Above does not work because boxes representing an "expression pattern":

```
MakeBoxes[g[a_], TraditionalForm] // FullForm
(* RowBox[List["g", "(", "a_", ")"]] *)
```

are something different than "box pattern" matching boxes representing any expression matching said "expression pattern". For simple pattern like the one above it's easy to write appropriate "box pattern" by hand:

```
System`Convert`TeXFormDump`maketex[RowBox[{"g", "(", a_, ")"}]] :=
    "\\g{" <> System`Convert`TeXFormDump`MakeTeX[a] <> "}"
    (* Note the use of MakeTeX with capital letters on RHS
       it's needed to properly use "BoxRules",
       that can be passed as an option to Convert`TeX`BoxesToTeX *)

TeXForm[g[a + 1]]
(* \g{a+1} *)
```

but for more complicated patterns it's very cumbersome.

Code samples tested in version 9.0.1.0 on Linux.

Answer (score 6):

To have a self-contained answer, I am repeating some of what the other answers have mentioned. For the TLDR folks, I've included all of the relevant code at the end of this answer.

**[`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm) design**

The way [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm) works is as follows:

1. Apply any [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm) formatting rules that match the entire expression. If one does, then return the result. Otherwise:
2. Convert the resulting expression into [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm) boxes.
3. Recursively transform the resulting [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm) boxes into a [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm) string.

**[`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format) issue**

The heart of the problem then is that during step 1, the [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm) definitions defined using [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format) are only applied once, and to the entire expression. This behavior is different from other [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format) definitions, which apply definitions recursively, because of the two-step process that [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm) uses. To fix this, there are two possibilities:

1. Use a [`ReplaceRepeated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceRepeated) strategy on the expression, that replaces parts at all levels (improve step 1).
2. Convert the [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm) format rules into [`MakeBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeBoxes) rules (improve step 2).

Possibility 1 is used by @jkuczm in his `TeXUtilities` package. I prefer possibility 2, so I will provide code to use this possibility.

**Why I don't like possibility 1**

The reason I don't like using possibility 1 is because the code needs to search the expression to figure out which [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format) rules should be used when doing the expression replacement. And, since a [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format) rule can include a symbol on the RHS that also needs to be converted,  the conversion of the expression really needs to be done again, including the search for all symbols that might need replacement in the new expression. Here is an example. Suppose we have the following [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format) rules:

```
Format[foo[x_], TeXForm] := bar[x, foo2[x]]
Format[foo2[x_], TeXForm] := bar2[x]
```

and we want to convert the expression:

```
foo[x] + Sin[x]
```

into [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm). In order to know which [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format) rules to use, we need to examine the expression, upon which we figure out that only `foo` needs to be replaced. So, if we replace it, we end up with:

```
bar[x, foo2[x]] + Sin[x]
```

Notice that we now have an expression with `foo2`. So, we need to repeat the above process, and we figure out that now only `foo2` needs to be replaced. So, we again replace, ending up with:

```
bar[x, bar2[x]] + Sin[x]
```

At this point, there are no more [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format) rules to apply, so we can go ahead and create the boxes corresponding to the above expression.

Now, with possibility 2, all we need to do is to define the [`MakeBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeBoxes) rules corresponding to the [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format) statements, and then applying [`MakeBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeBoxes) to the expression will automatically use these new [`MakeBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeBoxes) rules as needed. No need to repeatedly search the expression for symbols and perform replacements.

**Converting [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format) -> [`MakeBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeBoxes)**

One issue with converting [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format) rules into [`MakeBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeBoxes) rules is that [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm) uses [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm), and we don't want the [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm) specific [`MakeBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeBoxes) rules to be used during normal [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm) formatting. To avoid this, I will introduce a global variable (I've given it the name `$TeX`), and set this variable to [`True`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/True) when the expression is converted to [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm) boxes. Then, the code to convert [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format) rules into [`MakeBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeBoxes) rules can include a `$TeX` condition in the [`MakeBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeBoxes) rule, so that it only fires when the [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm) string is being created.

**Modifying built-in symbols**

I will be modifying built-in symbols, and you should be aware that there are risks associated with doing this.

Since I will be changing [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues)/[`UpValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpValues) of built-in symbols, it will be very convenient to make use of the `Initial` wrapper that I introduced in my [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153885/45431) to [How can one manually change the rule ordering](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/106068/45431):

```
Initial /: Verbatim[TagSetDelayed][Initial[sym_], lhs_, rhs_] := With[
    {
    new = Block[{sym},
        TagSetDelayed[sym, lhs, rhs];
        First @ Language`ExtendedDefinition[sym]
    ],
    protect = Unprotect[sym]
    },

    sym;
    Replace[new,
        Rule[values_, n:Except[{}]] :> (
            values[sym] = DeleteDuplicates@Join[n, values[sym]]
        ),
        {2}
    ];
    Protect@protect;
]
```

The basic idea is that using something like:

```
Initial[FresnelC] /: 
    MakeBoxes[FresnelC[x_], TraditionalForm] :=
    MakeBoxes[Defer[FresnelC][x], TraditionalForm]
```

will not only create the new [`FormatValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FormatValues), it will try to put this new format value at the beginning, so that it fires before any built - in format rules for the input:

```
FormatValues[FresnelC] //InputForm
```

> {HoldPattern[MakeBoxes[FresnelC[x_], TraditionalForm]] :> MakeBoxes[Defer[FresnelC][x], TraditionalForm], 
>    HoldPattern[MakeBoxes[FresnelC[BoxForm`a\$_], TraditionalForm] /; BoxForm`sufficientVersionQ[6.1]] :> 
>     TemplateBox[{MakeBoxes[BoxForm`a\$, TraditionalForm]}, "FresnelC"]}

Notice how the new [`MakeBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeBoxes) rule is first.

**`` Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX ``**

The first change is to modify the function `` Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX `` so that it sets the global variable `$TeX` to [`True`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/True) before creating [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm) boxes:

```
Initial[Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX] /: 
    Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX[e__] /; !TrueQ@$TeX := Block[
 {$TeX = True},
        Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX[e]
    ]
```

By design, `$TeX` will only get a value when it is blocked. This means that `!TrueQ@$TeX` will initially be [`True`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/True), and then after `$TeX` is blocked [`True`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/True), the condition will be false. The normal `` Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX `` code converts the expression into boxes using `MakeBoxes[.., TraditionalForm]`.

**Modifying [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format)**

*[`TagSetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSetDelayed) [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format)*

The next step is to modify [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format) so that it creates a `$TeX` conditioned [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm) [`MakeBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeBoxes) rule instead of a [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm) [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format) rule. Before I do that, let's see what kind of [`FormatValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FormatValues) [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm) typically creates:

```
foo /: Format[foo, TeXForm] := bar
FormatValues[foo] //FullForm
```

> List[RuleDelayed[HoldPattern[Format[foo,TeXForm]],bar]]

Instead of the above, I want to create a [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm) [`MakeBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeBoxes) rules. The following code does this:

```
Initial[Format] /: TagSetDelayed[sym_Symbol, Verbatim[Format][x_, TeXForm], rhs_] := With[
    {fmt = TraditionalForm},

    Initial[sym] /: MakeBoxes[x, fmt] /; $TeX := MakeBoxes[rhs, fmt]
]
```

Let's try the above Format again:

```
Clear[foo];
foo /: Format[foo, TeXForm] := bar

FormatValues[foo]
```

> {HoldPattern[MakeBoxes[foo, TraditionalForm] /; $TeX] :> 
>     MakeBoxes[bar, TraditionalForm]}

Notice that there is no [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm) rule any more, only a $TeX conditioned [`MakeBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeBoxes) rule. Also, the [`FormatValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FormatValues) is attached to `foo`, and not to [`MakeBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeBoxes). This is exactly what we want. Modifying [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format) to do this is easy when [`TagSetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSetDelayed) is used, since the relevant tag symbol (needed for the [`MakeBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeBoxes) rule) is given in the input.

*[`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed) [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format)*

A typical [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format) statement doesn't bother including the tag, so it would be nice to have this version work as well. Here is one way to do that:

```
Initial[Format] /: SetDelayed[Verbatim[Format][x_, TeXForm], rhs_] := With[
    {s = getTagSymbol[Format[x, TeXForm]], fmt = TraditionalForm},
    Replace[s,
        HoldForm[tag_] :> (
            Initial[tag] /: MakeBoxes[x, fmt] /; $TeX := MakeBoxes[rhs, fmt]
        )
    ]
]

SetAttributes[getTagSymbol, HoldFirst]

getTagSymbol[Format[x_, TeXForm]] := Module[{dummy, t},
    extractTag[Hold[Message[Format::tag, HoldForm@Format, _, tag_], False]] := t = tag;
    Internal`HandlerBlock[{Message, extractTag},
        Quiet[dummy[1] /: Format[x, TeXForm] := 1]
    ];
    t
]
```

The above code uses `getTagSymbol` to figure out what the correct tag is for a given [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format) LHS. It does this by using a dummy [`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module) variable as the tag, so that the [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format) rule will issue an error message telling us what the tag symbol should be. For instance:

```
dummy /: Format[x, InputForm] := 2
```

> Format::tag: Rule for Format of x can only be attached to x.
>
> $Failed

The `` Internal`HandlerBlock `` code intercepts this [`Message`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Message) to figure out what the tag symbol is, and a [`Quiet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quiet) is used because we are intentionally creating an error. A couple examples of `getTagSymbol` in action:

```
getTagSymbol[Format[x, TeXForm]]
getTagSymbol[Format[s_String, TeXForm]]
getTagSymbol[Format[foo[bar_], TeXForm]]
```

> HoldForm[x]
>
> HoldForm[String]
>
> HoldForm[foo]

Finally, here is an example of an ordinary [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format) statement:

```
Format[foo2, TeXForm] := bar2
FormatValues[foo2]
```

> {HoldPattern[MakeBoxes[foo2, TraditionalForm] /; $TeX] :> 
>     MakeBoxes[bar2, TraditionalForm]}

Again, there is no [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format) rule, and the [`MakeBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeBoxes) rule has the $TeX condition as desired. With the above rules, we now get:

```
ToString[foo + foo2, TeXForm]
```

> "\text{bar}+\text{bar2}"

The above code is sufficient for effectively making the [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm) [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format) rules act recursively.

**Examples**

*Example 1*

My first example will be similar to the OP example, except that I won't use a string RHS. Instead, I will define:

```
Format[x, TeXForm] := Style["x", FontWeight->"Bold"]
```

Then, the [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm) for a few examples are (I use [`CellPrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellPrint) so that all examples print, to avoid the issue discussed in [(138916)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/138916/45431)):

```
CellPrint@TextCell[ToString[#, TeXForm], "Output"]& /@ {x, x+1, Sin[x^2+1]};
```

> \pmb{\text{x}}
>
> \pmb{\text{x}}+1
>
> \sin \left(\pmb{\text{x}}^2+1\right)

And this is what they look like when using MathJax:

> $\pmb{\text{x}}$
>
> $\pmb{\text{x}}+1$
>
> $\sin \left(\pmb{\text{x}}^2+1\right)$

*Example 2*

This example comes from question [(153876)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153891/45431):

```
Format[FresnelC[x_], TeXForm] := Defer[FresnelC][x]
Format[CosIntegral[x_], TeXForm] := Defer[CosIntegral][x]
```

Then, nested functions do the right thing:

```
HoldForm[1+FresnelC[1+FresnelC[CosIntegral[z]]]] //TeXForm
```

> 1+\text{FresnelC}(1+\text{FresnelC}(\text{CosIntegral}(z)))

**OP Example**

Finally, let's look at the OP Example:

```
Format[x, TeXForm] := "{\\bf x}"

x //TeXForm
```

> \text{$\{\backslash \backslash $bf x$\}$}

What happened here? Without my [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format) changes, the [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format) statement will match x, and then return "{\b x}", short-circuiting the [`MakeBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeBoxes)/BoxesToTeX code. On the other hand, my [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format) changes mean that there are no [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format) statements to match, they have all been turned into [`MakeBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeBoxes) rules. So, there is no short-circuit, and the `BoxesToTeX` code applies its rules to the boxes to produce the output you see. It is the same thing as doing:

```
"{\\bf x}" //TeXForm
```

> \text{$\{\backslash \backslash $bf x$\}$}

I think this treatment of strings is rather suboptimal.

I think the way to proceed here is to change how the `BoxesToTeX` code deals with strings. [`MakeBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeBoxes) produces 2 kinds of strings. For example:

```
MakeBoxes[x] //FullForm
MakeBoxes["x"] //FullForm
```

> "x"
>
> "\"x\""

Basically, strings get converted into "quoted" strings, and everything else gets converted into "unquoted" strings. Currently, the `BoxesToTeX` code treats both kinds of strings equivalently. For example:

```
Convert`TeX`BoxesToTeX["\"{\\\\bf x}\""]
Convert`TeX`BoxesToTeX["{\\\\bf x}"]
```

> "\text{\$\{\backslash \backslash \$bf x\$\}\$}"
>
> "\text{\$\{\backslash \backslash \$bf x\$\}\$}"

So, one idea is to leave the conversions of "quoted strings" as they are, but to change the conversions of "unquoted strings". This way anybody who relies on the current behavior of `TeXForm[string]` will see that behavior maintained (although I suspect that nobody relies on the current behavior, and the best thing to do is to eliminate this string conversion behavior entirely).

The following code only changes the conversion of unquoted strings that are syntactically valid TeX:

```
System`Convert`TeXFormDump`maketex[s_String] /; !StringMatchQ[s, "\""~~___~~"\""] && SyntaxQ[s, TeXForm] := Replace[
    s,
    {
        n_ /; StringMatchQ[n, NumberString] :> n,
        w_?wordQ :> "\\operatorname{"<>w<>"}"
    }
]

wordQ[s_String] := Length @ StringSplit[s, WordBoundary] == 1
```

Note that numbers are left alone, single word strings (corresponding to operators) are wrapped in \operatorname, and other strings are just left alone (since they pass the [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm) [`SyntaxQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SyntaxQ) check).

Finally, the [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format) rule needs to be changed slightly because we want the [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm) boxes to not have quotes:

```
Format[x, TeXForm] := "{\\bf x}"

Block[{$TeX=True}, MakeBoxes[x, TraditionalForm]] //InputForm
```

> "\"{\\bf x}\""

Since the RHS of the [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format) statement is a string, the corresponding boxes are a quoted string. To make the corresponding boxes an unquoted string (so that the new string TeX code is used), we need to use [`RawBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RawBoxes):

```
Format[x, TeXForm] := RawBoxes @ "{\\bf x}"

Block[{$TeX=True}, MakeBoxes[x, TraditionalForm]] //InputForm
```

> "{\bf x}"

Now, the OP example should work:

```
x^2+1 //TeXForm
```

> {\bf x}^2+1

**Code**

Here is the relevant code in a single code block:

```
Initial /: Verbatim[TagSetDelayed][Initial[sym_], lhs_, rhs_] := With[
    {
    new = Block[{sym},
        TagSetDelayed[sym, lhs, rhs];
        First @ Language`ExtendedDefinition[sym]
    ],
    protect = Unprotect[sym]
    },

    sym;
    Replace[new,
        Rule[values_, n:Except[{}]] :> (
            values[sym] = DeleteDuplicates@Join[n, values[sym]]
        ),
        {2}
    ];
    Protect@protect;
]

Initial[Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX] /: 
    Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX[e__] /; !TrueQ@$TeX := Block[
 {$TeX = True},
        Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX[e]
    ]

Initial[Format] /: TagSetDelayed[sym_Symbol, Verbatim[Format][x_, TeXForm], rhs_] := With[
    {fmt = TraditionalForm},

    Initial[sym] /: MakeBoxes[x, fmt] /; $TeX := MakeBoxes[rhs, fmt]
]

Initial[Format] /: SetDelayed[Verbatim[Format][x_, TeXForm], rhs_] := With[
    {s = getTagSymbol[Format[x, TeXForm]], fmt = TraditionalForm},
    Replace[s,
        HoldForm[tag_] :> (
            Initial[tag] /: MakeBoxes[x, fmt] /; $TeX := MakeBoxes[rhs, fmt]
        )
    ]
]

SetAttributes[getTagSymbol, HoldFirst]

getTagSymbol[Format[x_, TeXForm]] := Module[{dummy, t},
    extractTag[Hold[Message[Format::tag, HoldForm@Format, _, tag_], False]] := t = tag;
    Internal`HandlerBlock[{Message, extractTag},
        Quiet[dummy[1] /: Format[x, TeXForm] := 1]
    ];
    t
]

System`Convert`TeXFormDump`maketex[s_String] /; !StringMatchQ[s, "\""~~___~~"\""] && SyntaxQ[s, TeXForm] := Replace[
    s,
    {
        n_ /; StringMatchQ[n, NumberString] :> n,
        w_?wordQ :> "\\operatorname{"<>w<>"}"
    }
]

wordQ[s_String] := Length @ StringSplit[s, WordBoundary] == 1
```

And, here again is the OP example:

```
(* OP example *)
Format[x, TeXForm] := RawBoxes @ "{\\bf x}"
x^2 + 1 //TeXForm
```

> {\bf x}^2+1