# How to convert formal symbols to standard ones in an expression?

Tags: symbols, built-in-symbols

*Mathematica* generates an expression sometimes using `\[Formal]` symbols. This is causing a problem with the `TeXForm` code generated as $\LaTeX$ is not able to process it. **To clarify**: The generated `TeXForm` should not include Unicode. The problem is that these are causing problem. So the solution should be such that, the result of applying `TeXForm` to the expression, should not produce Unicode.

Is there a way to make these expressions use normal symbols (normal `x` and `y`) so that I can generate $\LaTeX$ code from them that will work in my $\LaTeX$ document

```
 f = DifferentialRoot[Function[{y, x}, {y''[x] + y[x] == 0, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 1}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If I do `TeXForm[f]` on the above, the $\LaTeX$ code generated is not valid with TeXLive. 
I just need the expression `f` not to contain those dots above and below the symbols. Just normal symbols. One way is to use

```
f = DifferentialRoot[Function[{y, x}, {y''[x] + y[x] == 0, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 1}]]
    // OutputForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

which $\LaTeX$ can handle after `TeXForm` is applied to the above. But it will be nice to have `x` and `y` there instead.

Comment: An undocumented way of doing it (which I learned from [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/47687/245)) is: ``MapThread[Set, {Table[System`Convert`TeXFormDump`maketex[FromCharacterCode[63488 + i]], {i, 0, 25 + 26}], Table[FromCharacterCode[97 + i], {i, 0, 25}]~Join~Table[FromCharacterCode[65 + i], {i, 0, 25}]}];``  It seems to work from v8.0.4 all the way through 11.0.0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Interesting question with more complications than I anticipated.

If it is not necessary to replace every formal Symbol with the equivalent plain version, but instead arbitrarily with specified Symbols, you can use something like this:

```
SetAttributes[formalQ, HoldFirst]
formalQ[s_Symbol] := StringMatchQ[ToString@HoldForm@FullForm@s, "\\[Formal*]"]

expr = DifferentialRoot[Function[{y, x}, {y''[x] + y[x] == 0, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 1}]];

rep = {a, b, c, d, e};  (* new Symbols to use *)

old = Union @ Cases[expr, _Symbol?formalQ, {-1}]
new = Take[rep, Length @ old]
HoldForm @@ {expr} /. Thread[old -> new]
```

> ```
> DifferentialRoot[Function[{b,a},{b[a]+(b^\[Prime]\[Prime])[a]==0,b[0]==0,(b^\[Prime])[0]==1}]]
> ```

Note that I had to wrap `expr` in `HoldForm` as otherwise it automatically puts the Formal Symbols right back!

I am still working on the larger problem of replacing every Formal Symbol with its plain equivalent.
If I cannot find an internal look-up table I may have to build my own.

If you are only dealing with automatically-generated Formal Symbols you may only have a few to replace:

```
Holonomic`$DifferenceRootFormalSymbols

Holonomic`$DifferentialRootFormalSymbols
```

> ```
> {\[FormalY], \[FormalN]}
>
> {\[FormalY], \[FormalX]}
> ```

Therefore I would start with:

```
fix = {\[FormalY] :> y, \[FormalN] :> n, \[FormalX] :> x}
```

Comment: The generated code (from TeXForm) still contain those trouble invalid code) which are the \unicode. When I do `TeXForm[%]` on the result from your code, it still shows up with invlaid latex code that uses \unicode. The main reason I wanted to remove those `\Formal` and replace them with normal symbols is to avoid this `unicode` being generated. I'll update the question to make it more clear. You have removed all the other unicode, good, but one is still there. ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JgUt2.png)

Comment: @Nasser My mistake: that is `\[Function]`.  Please try: `HoldForm @@ {expr} /. Thread[old -> new] // StandardForm // TeXForm`

Comment: Thanks, yes, that is good. no unicode. It is not critical that `x` and `y` are being replaced by `a` and `b`. (x,y just happened to be more common to use) but will live with this solution. thank you

Comment: @Nasser Are all the formal symbols you're dealing with automatically generated?  If that's the case there may be only a few to replace, i.e. y, n, x.

Comment: yes. These are solutions from a set of differential equations that I am processing. So it will really include `x` and `y` as these are the same symbols used for each equation. It is just that M sometimes returns solutions using `\Formal` which causes problem for Latex. I am not using the solution for anything other than converting it to Latex.

Comment: There's an easier way to replace the formal symbols produced by `DifferentialRoot[]` and `DifferenceRoot[]`: `SetSystemOptions["HolonomicOptions" -> {"FunctionSymbol" -> y, "IteratorSymbol" -> n, "SequenceSymbol" -> y, "VariableSymbol" -> x}.]`

Comment: @J.M. They are Formal Symbols for a reason however!  I could not recommend that in good faith.

Comment: I know; just saying it's easier than having to tweak the stuff in the ``Holonomic`​`` context.