# Evaluate function defined by DifferentialRoot

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, series-expansion

I have the following sequence of rationals that I want to find the generating function of:

```
d1 = {1, 1, 0, -(1/3), -(1/12), 3/20, 7/60, -(1/35), -(271/3360), -(31/1440), 2953/75600, 54941/1663200, -(32377/3991680), -(313627/12355200), -(1562149/201801600), 57637519/4540536000, 81128389/6918912000, -(5841262799/2470051584000), -(16908002893/1852538688000), -(122799753991/38398074624000), 38177259047/8439137280000, 73864046480467/16127191342080000, -(422047957817/622452999168000), -(4070047619579/1156513438080000), -(899675774837639/640028142673920000), 9035541454237687/5333567855616000000, 21789055343201563/11556063687168000000, -(139475898744014537/802320993137664000000), -(5703599712765137243/4032177298845696000000), -(100308434035944184283/157254914654982144000000), 580014783870860474531/888388154219704320000000}
```

`FindSequenceFunction` gives a `DifferenceRoot` object that can be evaluated to recover the values of the sequence.

```
sf = FindSequenceFunction[d1]
(*DifferenceRoot[Function[{y, n}, {(-2 - n^2) y[n] + 3 (1 + n + n^2) y][1 + n]] - 3 (1 + n)^2 y][2 + n]] +  3 (1 + n) (2 + n]) y][3 + n]] == 0, y[1] == 1, y][2] == 1, y][3] == 0}]]*)
```

By the way, why does Mathematice use these `\[FormalN]` variables in output like this?

```
sf[5]==-1/12
(*True*)
```

Similarly, `FindGeneratingFunction` returns a `DifferentialRoot` object:

```
gf[x_] = FindGeneratingFunction[d1, x]
(*DifferentialRoot[Function[{y,x},{(-6+3 x-3 x^2+2 x^3) y[x]+x (6-3 x+x^3) (y'[x]+x^2 (-3+3 x-3 x^2+x^3) y''[x]==0,y[0]==0,y'[0]==1}]][x]/x*)
```

However, evaluating `gf` does not seem to work. Also, when I try to integrate the differential equation found by `FindGeneratingFunction` directly using `NDSolve` the input is returned unevaluated.

I can obtain an approximation to the generating function as

```
f1[x_] = Dot[d1, x^Range[0, Length[d1] - 1]]
```

but this is of course only valid for small `x` and I'd prefer having a differential equation that I can solve numerically to working with truncated power series of large degree.

> **Question**: How can I evaluate the `DifferentialRoot` object returned by `FindGeneratingFunction` in the example described above?

Comment: Rather than verifying just one instance of sf you can verify all of d1 with `d1 == sf /@ Range[Length[d1]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, evaluating gf does not seem to work

When Mathematica returns `DifferentialRoot` as solution to a differential equation, it really means M could not solve the ODE.   This is not the necessarily the case with `DifferenceRoot` as you found out (I do not know much about DifferenceRoot, but I've seen DifferentialRoot before many times).  Here is an example:

```
ode = -y[x] + (1 + x)*Derivative[2][y][x] + x^2*Derivative[3][y][x] == 0;
DSolve[ode, y[x], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can't use `y[x]` generated above. The above really means M could not solve the ODE.  For your case, the ODE is

```
ode = (-6 + 3*x - 3*x^2 + 2*x^3)*y[x] + x*(6 - 3*x + x^3)*Derivative[1][y][x] + 
          x^2*(-3 + 3*x - 3*x^2 + x^3)*Derivative[2][y][x] == 0;
ic = {y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 1};
DSolve[{ode, ic}, y[x], x];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However, if you want the solution to the above ODE, Maple 18.1 gives this very complicated solution in terms of HeunG function.

```
restart;
ode := (-6 + 3*x - 3*x^2 + 2*x^3)*y(x) + x*(6 - 3*x + x^3)*diff(y(x),x) + 
         x^2*(-3 + 3*x - 3*x^2 + x^3)*diff(y(x),x$2)= 0;
ic := y(0)= 0, D(y)(0)= 1:
sol:=dsolve({ode, ic},y(x));
```

gives

```
y(x) = (-HeunG((2*I)*sqrt(3)/(I*sqrt(3)-3), 864/((I*sqrt(3)+3)^3*
    (I*sqrt(3)-3)^2), 1+I*sqrt(2), (72*I)*(sqrt(6)-(3*I)*sqrt(2)-(2*I)*sqrt(3)-
    6)*sqrt(2)/((I*sqrt(3)+3)^3*(I*sqrt(3)-3)^2), 1, 1, (-1+I*sqrt(3)+2^(2/3))
    /(I*sqrt(3)-3))*_C2/HeunG((2*I)*sqrt(3)/(I*sqrt(3)-3), 864/((I*sqrt(3)+3)^3*
   (I*sqrt(3)-3)^2), 1-I*sqrt(2), -(144*(sqrt(6)-(3*I)*sqrt(2)-I*sqrt(3)-
   3))/((I*sqrt(3)+3)^3*(I*sqrt(3)-3)^2), 1, 1, (-1+I*sqrt(3)+2^(2/3))
   /(I*sqrt(3)-3))+1/HeunG((2*I)*sqrt(3)/(I*sqrt(3)-3), 864/((I*sqrt(3)+3)^3*
   (I*sqrt(3)-3)^2), 1-I*sqrt(2), -(144*(sqrt(6)-(3*I)*sqrt(2)-I*sqrt(3)-
   3))/((I*sqrt(3)+3)^3*(I*sqrt(3)-3)^2), 1, 1, (-1+I*sqrt(3)+2^(2/3))
   /(I*sqrt(3)-3)))*x*HeunG((2*I)*sqrt(3)/(I*sqrt(3)-3), 864/((I*sqrt(3)+3)^3*
   (I*sqrt(3)-3)^2), 1-I*sqrt(2), -(144*(sqrt(6)-(3*I)*sqrt(2)-I*sqrt(3)-
   3))/((I*sqrt(3)+3)^3*(I*sqrt(3)-3)^2), 1, 1, (-1-2^(2/3)*x+I*sqrt(3)+2^(2
   /3))/(I*sqrt(3)-3))+_C2*x*HeunG((2*I)*sqrt(3)/(I*sqrt(3)-3), 
   864/((I*sqrt(3)+3)^3*(I*sqrt(3)-3)^2), 1+I*sqrt(2), (72*I)*(sqrt(6)-
   (3*I)*sqrt(2)-(2*I)*sqrt(3)-6)*sqrt(2)/((I*sqrt(3)+3)^3*(I*sqrt(3)-3)^2), 1, 
   1, (-1-2^(2/3)*x+I*sqrt(3)+2^(2/3))/(I*sqrt(3)-3))
```

> By the way, why does Mathematice use these [FormalN] variables in
>   output like this?

I do not know. I do not like them either. (most likely so they do not clash with your own symbols). MrWizard has a function here that can help remove them:

[How to convert formal symbols to standard ones in an expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55547/how-to-convert-formal-symbols-to-standard-ones-in-an-expression)

**Update**: After posting this, I asked Maple experts on the constant _C2 showing up in the solution of dsolve. Thanks to their help, it turned out the ode has wrong initial conditions. At $x=0$ the ode does not exist (the coefficients of the y' and y'' become zero). So the ODE generated by Mathematica, or the initial conditions that came with it, or both, are not correct. i.e. they lead to singularity at x=0.

This might indicate a bug in `FindGeneratingFunction` but I am not sure. Either way, the ODE given above can't be solved uniquely given the initial conditions that come with it.

Comment: Thanks! I also used FriCAS' `guessADE()` to guess an algebraic differential equation for the generating function of my sequence and obtained `{(x^3 - 3 x^2 + 3 x - 3) y''[x] + (3 x^2 - 6 x + 3) y'[x] + (3 x - 3) y[x] == 0, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 1}`, which Mma solves in terms of ordinary Gauss hypergeometric functions `Hypergeometric2F1`.

Comment: @Eckhard Ok. The ode you obtained from FriCAS looks ok. no singularity at x=0. This probably mean there might be a bug in Mathematica `FindGeneratingFunction` here. This might be a good example to send to support@wolfram.com to look at.