# Define a function inside a function when the function is passed as a parameter

Tags: function-construction, scoping

I'm trying to pass a function of a variable (t) into a module where I will do lots of manipulation (such as taking the derivitave).  But I'm not sure what the right way is.  I have a workaround (f2), but it doesn't seem like the right way.  What's the best practice in this case? thanks!

```
f[t_] = t^2;

function[f_] := Module[{},
 f1[t_] = f;
 f2[t2_] = f /. t -> t2;

 Print["f[2] = ", f[2]];
 Print["f/.t->2 = ", f /. t -> 2];
 Print["f1[2] = ", f1[2]];
 Print["f2[2] = ", f2[2]];

 Print["f'[2] = ", f'[2]];
 Print["f1'[2] = ", f1'[2]];
 Print["f2'[2] = ", f2'[2]];
];


 function[f[t]]
```

> ```
> f[2] = (t^2)[2]
>
> f/.t->2 = 4
>
> f1[2] = t^2
>
> f2[2] = 4
>
> f'[2] = ((t^2)')[2]
>
> f1'[2] = 0
>
> f2'[2] = 4
> ```

Comment: related: [Compute Hessian of function symbolically](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/123403/5478)

Answer (score 2):

Define `f` with [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) ( := ) rather than `Set` ( = ), and pass it by name as you would a built-in function. It will perform just like a built-in function.

```
f[t_] := t^2
g[h_] :=
  Block[{df, t},
   df[t_] = h'[t];
   Integrate[df[t], t]]
g[f]
```

> `t^2`

```
g[1 + Sin[#]^2 &]
```

> `-(1/2) Cos[2 t]`

This result is correct because it differs from `1 + Sin[t]^2` only by a constant.

`Simplify[-(1/2) Cos[2 t] - Sin[t]^2]`

> `-1/2`

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately, f[t] is defined earlier in the code (sometimes it is an interpolated function) and comes in as a Set (=).

Comment: @samuelSchweighart. The remark about `Set` and `SetDelay` apply to your definition for `f`, not in general. The remark about passing the function in by name holds generally. But look at the 2nd example. The function passed in there wasn't defined with either `Set` or `SetDelayed` and it still works.