# How to make a matrix of derivatives?

Tags: matrix, map, calculus-and-analysis

For example I can construct:

```
  row1 = D[f(x,y),x,#]&/@{x,y}
  row2 = D[f(x,y),x,#]&/@{x,y}
```

then:

```
matrix = {row1,row2}
```

That yields a matrix like:

$$\left(\matrix{\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} \quad\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}\\ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}\quad \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}}\right)$$

**Question:** how to construct such matrix in a single line of code?

Comment: `Outer[Dt[f, #1, #2] &, #, #] &@{x, y}`

Comment: Also `D[f[x, y], {{x, y}, 2}]`.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/123403/compute-hessian-of-function-symbolically

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [`D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/D.html) (search for Hessian):

```
D[f[x, y], {{x, y}, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Ok that works, but when I do that I cannot perform matrix summation, Mathematica don't evaluate the operation (even if I use Evaluate).

Comment: For example, for D[f[x, y], {{x, y}, 2}]+D[g[x, y], {{x, y}, 2}]

Comment: Ok, I solved that, I was placing a //MatrixForm that was messing the evaluation, thank you for your helpful answer

Comment: @Saavestro You can find out more about the `MatrixForm` problem [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3098/why-does-matrixform-affect-calculations).  -- And you're welcome! Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

I think `Tuples` is the missing element for you:

```
TraditionalForm[
 Partition[D[f[x, y], Sequence @@ #] & /@ Tuples[{x, y}, 2], 2]
]
```

[image]

Comment: `Outer` is more elegant solution.