# Compute the Hessian matrix of a function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, matrix

To compute the gradient of a function, it can be made with matematica using Grad[f[x,y],{x,y}]

Suprisingly, it's not possible to compute the Hessian matrix (something as HessianMatrix[f[x,y],{x,y}], doesn't exist (I check in Wolfram website [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hessian.html), but nothing relevant). Is it possible that mathematica can't compute the Hessian of a function ? And if no (what I guess), how can I do ?

Comment: Here's a link in here:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/123403/compute-hessian-of-function-symbolically  Also, very convenient now to just google anything you want in mathematica to find it usually here.  That's what I did, I just googled:  "Hessian matrix in mathematica" to get to that link.

Comment: `D[f[x, y], {{x, y}, 2}]`

Comment: @Dominic: Thanks a lot for your message. Indeed, I found this link, but trying to apply it, didn't work with me... I'll see if I can apply it properly.

Comment: @cvgmt: Definitely much better. Thank a lot.

Comment: Here's another from Mathworld:  HessianH[f_, x_List?VectorQ] := D[f, {x, 2}]

Comment: @Dominic: It didn't work when I wrote that as well...

Comment: Ok sorry.  You may wish to click the up arrow on cvgmt's answer.  We do that in here if the comment is helpful and if someone actually post code below and it answers your question, consider clicking the up arrow on that post  as well as the check signifying the question is answered.

Comment: @Dominic: Unfortunately, my score is to low for that (I can't up vote comment).

Comment: Presumably, you entered something wrong when testing solution by @Dominic. With `HessianH[f_, x_List?VectorQ] := D[f, {x, 2}]` then `HessianH[f[x, y], {x, y}] == D[f[x, y], {{x, y}, 2}]` evaluates to `True`