# How to separately define TraditionalForm and TeXForm

Tags: output-formatting, latex

According to the documentation, [`TeXForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm.html#365832752) uses the `TraditionalForm` formatting to generate the TeX code.

However, for some cases, this is not ideal.  For example, it would be better to display the [Feynman slash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_slash_notation) $\sum_\mu \gamma_\mu p^\mu$ as

`CenterDot[γ, p]`$\equiv \gamma\cdot p$ in `TraditionalForm` in the Mathematica front end,

but as `\slashed{p}`$\equiv p\!\!/\,\,$ in `TeXForm` (using the [slashed package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/slashed?lang=en)).

How do I tell `TeXForm` that each time `CenterDot[γ, p_]` is encountered in an expression, it should be formatted `\slashed{p}`?

I'm looking for a back-end solution, so that `TeXForm` on an input or output would automatically give the correct code.  Solutions requiring more than the minimal `TeXForm` to generate $\TeX$ code will not be accepted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [this answer by @jkuczm](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/47687/245), the following works for me in version 10.3:

```
slashed /: MakeBoxes[slashed[x_], TraditionalForm | StandardForm] := 
 RowBox[{"\[Gamma]\[CenterDot]", ToBoxes[x]}]

System`Convert`TeXFormDump`maketex[
  RowBox[{"\[Gamma]\[CenterDot]", a_}]] := 
 "\\slashed{" <> System`Convert`TeXFormDump`MakeTeX[a] <> "}"

CenterDot[\[Gamma], x_] := slashed[x]
```

I define an auxiliary function `slashed` and give it different formatting rules for the different forms. The I define `CenterDot` for the special case where the first argument is `γ`, to be interpreted as `slashed`. Here is a screen shot of the formatting:

[image: screen shot]

Comment: This is a perfect solution.  As a note to myself (and others), the argument of ``System`Convert`TeXFormDump`maketex`` should be a box structure in `TraditionalForm`.