# How to use Format in TeXForm keeping expression as shown in Format?

Tags: output-formatting, latex, format

I have expression `expr = int[1 - x + x^2 - x^3 + x^4 - x^5, x]` and I want to convert it to Latex. But want to replace `int` by `Integrate` but without evaluating it.

I tried using `Format` and that works inside Mathematica. It prints correctly on the screen.

But when using `TeXForm` on `expr` it ignored the `Format`.

Here is MWE

```
ClearAll[int, x]
Format[int[e_,x_],StandardForm] := Defer[Integrate[e, x]]
expr = int[1-x+x^2-x^3+x^4-x^5,x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And that what I want in Latex. But when now I do

```
TeXForm[expr]
```

it gives

```
"\text{int}\left(-x^5+x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1,x\right)"
```

Which compiles as

[image]

Instead, I wanted the latex be generated based on the display it shows on the screen from `Format` which should be something like

```
"\int { \left(-x^5+x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1 \right) \, dx }"
```

so it matches what it shows above on the screen.

I looked at this post [Format and TeXForm does not work as expected](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47417/format-and-texform-does-not-work-as-expected)  and tried few answers there, but so far could not make anything work. It is almost 10 years old and many things changed and I was lost of the complexity of answers and what I am supposed to do.

All the expressions I wan to apply this to have the form

```
 int[ .... , x]
```

Does there exist a  simple solution to this problem?

I thought about just parsing `int[..., x]` myself to pick up the `...` and the `x` using pattern matching, and then converting everything manually to `Defer[ Integrate[...,x]]` and then I can do

```
 TeXForm[Defer[Integrate[ 1-x+x^2-x^3+x^4-x^5 , x]]]
```

And this now works. it gives

```
 \int \left(-x^5+x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1\right) \, dx
```

But was hoping to avoid parsing it myself and let `Format` do it if possible.

V 13.3.1 on windows 10

Comment: I am just adding this as a comment as I think this may not be what you want, but why not replace `int` with `Integrate` right before converting to `TeXForm`?
$$ $$
`ClearAll[int, x]`
`expr = int[1 - x + x^2 - x^3 + x^4 - x^5, x]`

`new = Apply[Inactive[Integrate][#, x] &, expr];`
`TeXForm[new]`
`(*\int \left(-x^5+x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1\right)dx*)`

Comment: Also `expr // StandardForm // TeXForm` produces your desired output with no changes to your MWE. I am worried I am missing something in the problem though as this seems too simple...maybe I haven't had enough coffee yet.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to use `Format`? Because you can also do something like `int[1 - x + x^2 - x^3 + x^4 - x^5, x] /. 
  int -> Inactive[Integrate] // TeXForm`. That makes it so that you don't *manually* have to do copies and replace, and of course you can always package that into your own `tExfORM[expr_] := expr /. int -> Inactive[Integrate] // TeXForm`.  Alternatively, perhaps you can just set `int = Inactive[Integrate]` and do whatever algebraic manipulations you need to do, then just `TeXForm` at the end.

Comment: @ydd You are right, I have not tried that. `TeXForm[StandardForm[expr]]` works. If I leave  `StandardForm` form, then it does not work. Thanks.

Comment: @march you are right, that is also good workaround. I never used `Format` before and this is first time I try it.

Comment: TeXForm uses TraditionalForm formatting, so define `Format[int[e_,x_],TraditionalForm] := Defer[Integrate[e, x]]` instead

Comment: @ydd FYI, I found standardForm breaks things. See this screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7bC7.png)   you see how it does not translate correctly when using standardForm in this example! I am on 13.3 windows 10.